# Differential equation $y'' - \frac{2y}{x^2} = 3\ln(-x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello there I am trying to solve
$$y'' - \frac{2y}{x^2} = \ln(-x)$$

I get this differential equation from book - filippov differential equations [link on book](http://kvm.gubkin.ru/pub/uok/FilippovDU.pdf) (problem #606).
And same way I have solve (in this book)
$$y = \frac{C_1}{x} + \left[ C_2 - \frac{1}{3}\ln(-x) + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x) \right] x^2$$

But I can not get this solve.

My solve:
$$y'' - \frac{2y}{x^2} = \ln(-x)$$
$$x^2y'' - 2y = x^2 \ln(-x)$$
$$k(k-1) - 2 = 0$$
$$k_1 = -1, k_2= 2, y_1=x^{-1}, y_2=x^2$$
$$y_0 = C_1y_1 + C_2y_2 = \frac{C_1}{x} + C_2x^2$$

$$W = \begin{vmatrix}
y_1 &y_2 \\
y'_1 &y'_2
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
x^{-1} &x^2 \\
-x^{-2} &2x
\end{vmatrix} = 2+1 = 3$$

$$W_1 = \begin{vmatrix}
0  &  y_2 \\
g(x) & *
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
0 & x^2 \\
\ln(-x) & 2x
\end{vmatrix} = -x^2 \ln(-x)$$

$$W_2 = \begin{vmatrix}
y_1   & 0 \\
*     &g(x)  
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
x^{-1} &0 \\
-x^{-2} & \ln(-x)
\end{vmatrix} = \frac{\ln(-x)}{x}$$

$$y_h = u_1y_1 + u_2y_2$$

$$u_1 = \int{\frac{W_1}{W}} = \int{\frac{-x^2 \ln(-x)}{3}} = -\frac{1}{9}x^3(3\ln(-x) - 1)$$
$$u_2 = \int{\frac{W_2}{W}} = \int{\frac{3\ln(-x)}{x}} = \frac{3}{2}\ln^2(-x)$$

$$y_h = -\frac{1}{9}x^3(3\ln(-x) - 1) x^{-1} + \frac{3}{2}\ln^2(-x) x^2 = -\frac{1}{3}x^2 \ln(-x) - \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{3}{2}\ln^2(-x) x^2$$

$$y = y_0 + y_h$$

$$y = \frac{C_1}{x} + C_2x^2 - \frac{1}{3}x^2 \ln(-x) - \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{3}{2}\ln^2(-x) x^2$$

General solution:

$$y = \frac{C_1}{x} + \left[ C_2 - \frac{1}{3} \ln(-x) - \frac{1}{9} + \frac{3}{2}\ln^2(-x) \right] x^2$$

Please help me where I'm wrong?
May be in book have wrong?

Comment: I think you might have the equation incorrect - it should be $$y'' - \frac {2y}{x^2} = 3 \ln (-x)$$

Comment: Always you can check the solution just writing $y$ in the ODE. In this case in $y''-2y/x^2=\ln(-x)$.

Comment: Please check the inhomogeneous term. If it is $3\ln(-x)$, you need to correct the variation of parameters calculation accordingly.

Comment: One could also apply the method of undetermined coefficients, the right side term falls into the admissible class. Then $y_0(x)=\ln(-x)(A+B\ln(-x))x^2$ has to be inserted into the equation to then compare coefficients.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers
I fixed bugs.
But solution is not correct. I see mistake $-\frac{1}{9}$ 
$$x^2y'' - 2y = x^2 3\ln(-x)$$

$$y_h = -\frac{1}{9}x^3(3\ln(-x) - 1) x^{-1} + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x) x^2 = -\frac{1}{3}x^2 \ln(-x) - \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x) x^2$$
$$y = \frac{C_1}{x} + C_2x^2 -\frac{1}{3}x^2 \ln(-x) - \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x) x^2$$
$$y = \frac{C_1}{x} + \left[C_2 - \frac{1}{3} \ln(-x) - \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x)\right] x^2$$

Comment: If you use the modified right side, then the factor $3$ cancels in $W_k/W$, you should not get a denominator $9$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Why not?
$$u_1 = \int{\frac{W_1}{W}} = \int{\frac{-x^2 3\ln(-x)}{3}} = \int{-x^2 \ln(-x)} = - \frac{1}{9}x^3(3\ln(-x) - 1) = - \frac{1}{3}x^3\ln(-x) + \frac{x^3}{9}$$

Comment: I checked on Wolframalf's website and 1/9 also exists there.

I think in solution:
$$y = \frac{C_1}{x} + [C_2 - \frac{1}{3} \ln(-x) + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x)] x^2$$

$\frac{1}{9}$ may be added in $C_2$

Comment: Ah yes, ok. Then the error was in your original computation where the denominator should have been 27.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You can also approach it as follows:
\begin{align*}
y'' - \frac{2y}{x^{2}} = \ln(-x) & \Longleftrightarrow x^{2}y'' - 2y = x^{2}\ln(-x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y'' + 2xy') - (2xy' + 2y) = x^{2}\ln(-x)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y')' - (2xy)' = x^{2}\ln(-x)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

I found error (thank you very much everyone in comment)
First error in differential equation:
$$y'' - \frac{2y}{x^2} = 3 \ln(-x)$$

Solution:

$$x^2y'' - 2y = x^2 3\ln(-x)$$
$$k(k-1) - 2 = 0$$
$$k_1 = -1, k_2= 2, y_1=x^{-1}, y_2=x^2$$
$$y_0 = C_1y_1 + C_2y_2 = \frac{C_1}{x} + C_2x^2$$
$$g(x) = 3 \ln(-x)$$

$$W = \begin{vmatrix}
y_1 &y_2 \\
y'_1 &y'_2
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
x^{-1} &x^2 \\
-x^{-2} &2x
\end{vmatrix} = 2+1 = 3$$

$$W_1 = \begin{vmatrix}
0  &  y_2 \\
g(x) & *
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
0 & x^2 \\
3\ln(-x) & 2x
\end{vmatrix} = -x^2 3 \ln(-x)$$

$$W_2 = \begin{vmatrix}
y_1   & 0 \\
*     &g(x)  
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
x^{-1} &0 \\
-x^{-2} & 3\ln(-x)
\end{vmatrix} = \frac{3\ln(-x)}{x}$$

$$y_h = u_1y_1 + u_2y_2$$

$$u_1 = \int{\frac{W_1}{W}} = \int{\frac{-x^2 3\ln(-x)}{3}} = \int{-x^2 \ln(-x)} = - \frac{1}{9}x^3(3\ln(-x) - 1) = - \frac{1}{3}x^3\ln(-x) + \frac{x^3}{9}$$

$$u_2 = \int{\frac{W_2}{W}} = \int{\frac{\frac{3\ln(-x)}{x}}{3}} = \int{\frac{\ln(-x)}{x}} = \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x)$$

$$y_h = (- \frac{1}{3}x^3\ln(-x) + \frac{x^3}{9}) x^{-1} + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x) x^2 = -\frac{1}{3}x^2 \ln(-x) + \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x) x^2$$

$$y = y_0 + y_h$$

$$y = \frac{C_1}{x} + C_2x^2 -\frac{1}{3}x^2 \ln(-x) + \frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x) x^2$$

$$y = \frac{C_1}{x} + [C_2 - \frac{1}{3} \ln(-x) + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x)] x^2$$

And because $\frac{1}{9}$ - constant, we can combine with $C_2$

General solution:
$$y = \frac{C_1}{x} + [C_2 - \frac{1}{3} \ln(-x) + \frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-x)] x^2$$